# My average of my ArrayList is incorrect

Tags: java, arraylist, average

```
static ArrayList<Integer> gradeScore = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(100);
    add(50);
    add(90);
}};
public static void findAvg(){
    int totalSum = 0;
    for(int i: gradeScore){
        totalSum = totalSum+ i;

    int amountOfGrades = gradeScore.size();
    double gradeAvg =(totalSum/amountOfGrades);
    System.out.println(gradeAvg);
    }

}
```

When I run the method i get
The scores are [100, 50, 90]
Your average is
33.0
50.0
80.0
Can someone tell me what to do to only get one average?

Comment: you are calculating and printing the average in each iteration for loop.  just do it once after your for loop

Comment: Better way to build your list: `static List<Integer> gradeScore = Arrays.asList(100, 50, 90)`, or if it *has* to be an `ArrayList`, use  `static ArrayList<Integer> gradeScore = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(100, 50, 90))`

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i: gradeScore){
        totalSum = totalSum+ i;
}
    int amountOfGrades = gradeScore.size();
    double gradeAvg =(totalSum/amountOfGrades);
    System.out.println(gradeAvg);
```

Curly brace is the problem. close the for..loop after `totalSum = totalSum+i`

Answer (score 0):

You run the other 3 lines of code `n` times, which is not required.

You may add it once and then show it at the end.

```
int totalSum = 0;
for(int i: gradeScore){
    totalSum = totalSum+ i;
}
int amountOfGrades = gradeScore.size();
double gradeAvg =(totalSum/amountOfGrades);
System.out.println(gradeAvg);
```

---

Also your average division truncates the decimal part, cast it to a double if you don't want that.

```
double gradeAvg = (double) (totalSum/amountOfGrades);
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop didn't ended properly or missing for loop closing brace.. I tried to customize your solution a bit

```
static ArrayList<Integer> gradeScore = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
    {
        add(100);
        add(50);
        add(90);
    }
};

public static void findAvg() {
    int totalSum = 0;
    for (int i : gradeScore)
        totalSum += i;
    System.out.println(totalSum / (1.0 * gradeScore.size()));
}
```